# Date trunc and partition by subject

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a db with column `name` containing different companies names, and column `date`, where each company has all days of the year ( so `date`= 1/3/2007 appear for `name`=x and also for `name`=y).

I need to calculate monthly profit **separately** for each company.

I am able to do this for a single company:

```
    WITH BS AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT ON(date_trunc('month', date)) date_trunc('month', date), date_num, name, profit as c
    FROM history
    WHERE name IN ('X', 'Y') //companies
    ),
    LG AS (
    SELECT date_num, name, c, LAG(c,1) OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY date_num) o
    FROM BS 
    )

    SELECT date_num, name, c, o,  100 * ( (c - o)/o )  as trends
    FROM LG
    ORDER BY date_num  DESC
```

This works for a **single** company, but if I have multiple (X+Y) how can I separate the `DISTINCT` date selection for each `name` ?

**desired output (assuming each `name` as all possible dates of the year):**

```
name  date      trend

X     1.2.2020.   3
X     1.3.2020.   4
X     1.4.2020.   7
Y     1.2.2020.   9
Y     1.3.2020.   2
Y     1.4.2020.   5
```

**Original data** :

```
name  date      profit  date_num

X     1.2.2020.   2     1638316800 (EPOCH DATES)
X     2.2.2020.   1     ....
X     3.2.2020.   6     ..
Y     1.2.2020.   5
Y     2.2.2020.   4
Y     3.2.2020.   2
```

Comment: Sample data and the desired output would help.

Comment: Thanks, I edited the desired output. Is it more clear?

Comment: This looks more like you want a `GROUP  BY`, not a `DISTINCT ON` - but with DISTINCT ON you have to use an `ORDER BY` to get sensible results to begin with.

Comment: Unfortunatelythe the full picture it's not clear still. What is `date_num`? for example. Can you share sample data?

Comment: @Serg I edited again, sorry.  date_num is just the epoch date(another representation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using DISTINCT ON requires a proper ORDER BY to return the correct rows.

```
WITH BS AS (
   SELECT DISTINCT ON(date_trunc('month', date), name) date, name, date_num, profit c
   FROM history
   WHERE name IN ('X', 'Y') 
   ORDER BY date_trunc('month', date), name, date_num
), LG AS (
      SELECT date_num, name, c, LAG(c,1) OVER(PARTITION BY name ORDER BY date_num) o
      FROM BS 
)
SELECT date_num, name, c, o,  100.0 * ( (c - o)/o )  as trends
FROM LG
ORDER BY date_num DESC
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=9f33d64d663bc0e0d6b34a913be8b826)

Comment: @baltiturg,  You need to mention all the columns which unique combinations you want in the result set. Month+ name in your case.  The other way is to `ROW_NUMBER()` the rows withib a group and take the rn=1, A lot of `ROW_NUMBER()` examples over here.

Comment: this actually works strange, with one company dates are the beginning of month, but with 2, the dates are not the beginning of each month anymore.

Comment: Added  one more sort column .. `, date_num` to ensure the first day of month is selected.

Comment: thanks man! it solved the problem, but why? you already sort with date, why its it not enough?

Comment: Sorting  by month alone doesn't gurantee the raw will be of the first day of month.